# Graph construction in Prolog

Tags: prolog

i am trying to implemente an access control system in prolog, and in some point of my code i have these two rules :

```
canRead(S,O):- readPermissionsRole(R,O),holds(S,R).
canWrite(S,O):-writePermissionRole(R,O),holds(S,R).
```

what i need to do is to have as result a graph representing the results of the two rules ; we have an edge from O to S if canRead(S,O). and an edge from S to O if canWrite(S,O). 
how can this be done ?
thank you .

Comment: Define how you want to represent your graph in Prolog. And can you give a simple example? What is the "universe" of possible values for `S` and `O` and how is that determined? In other words, how would you define `valid_s(S)` and `valid_o(O)`, for example?

Comment: @lurker ...the variables S and O represents Sbjects and Oubjects that i will instantiate using the assert predicat in the beggining ....the idea is that i have subjects and objects and Roles .......Roles have reading and writing permissions over Objects .. and Subjects can hold roles , so roles will have reading and writing permissions too over objects . is these permissions that i want to put in a graph like described in my question an edge from O to S if canRead(S,O). and an edge from S to O if canWrite(S,O).

Comment: You can create them separately, then combine: `findall(O-S, canRead(S,O), Readers)` and `findall(S-O, canWrite(S, O), Writers)`, and then `append(Readers, Writers, Edges)`. Here, an "edge" looks like `a-b`.

Comment: @lurker ........create what separatly ? ..i am sorry this is my first time i try to use graphs in prolog .

Comment: As I showed, I created your readers and writers separately, then I combined them. All the code is in my prior comment. Prolog doesn't know what graphs are, you just have to define them yourself. In this case, I defined an edge to be `node-node`.

Comment: thanks @lurker ...i will try it

Comment: @lurker ...... I get results but not all of them, some results are messing in the `findall(O-S, canRead(S,O), Readers)` results .....and i dont get results on the combination ....check my answer

Comment: @StambouliAouadoud you don't have much information in your original question to go on, so I'm not sure what else I can suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable values do not persist across separate queries.

To obtain all the edges, you need to do something like this:

```
readers_and_writers(Edges) :--
    findall(O-S, canRead(S,O), Readers),
    findall(S-O, canWrite(S, O), Writers),
    append(Readers, Writers, Edges).
```